# Jenkins trigger build via branch merge on reappearing branch

Tags: git, jenkins

I have three branches `master`, `b1` and `b2`. The development for each project in our group works as follows: All development is pulled from and pushed to `b2`, we merge it into `b1` as soon as there is no more code to develop, we do regression testing with the code in `b1`, deploy it manually using Jenkins and finally merge `b1` it into master.
Now, because I am tired of all the merging and manual stuff, I want to use Jenkins all the way, i.e., a build is triggered when a change occurs in `b1`, i.e., when the code is done, regression testing is launched and we have the final tested build with docs in the end.

I know how to set up a trigger when there is a change in a branch but I am wondering how to do it since the branch `b1` to which the trigger is hooked, is also merged afterwards (manually) into `master`. Is the this again a trigger for a build? And if I recreate the branch at a later time, does Jenkins simply recognize that it has to work with the new branch (identical name as the old one)?

Comment: Can you share, by editing your question, any attempts you have made on this? Any code or screenshots of the Jenkins UI? This will aid others in providing specific answers.

Comment: Sure, I can, brb.